# How can i get the ID's of users ,who are login with facebook account details in to my app

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

```
private void loginToFacebook() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());

                        try {
                            // PROFILE DETAILS AND FRIENDS COUNTER
                            String queryUserInfo = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = me()";

                            Bundle paramUserInfo = new Bundle();
                            paramUserInfo.putString("method", "fql.query");
                            paramUserInfo.putString("query", queryUserInfo);

                            String responseUserInfo = Util.facebook
                                    .request(paramUserInfo);

                            JSONArray JAUserData = new JSONArray(
                                    responseUserInfo);

                            for (int i = 0; i < JAUserData.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject JOUserData = JAUserData
                                        .getJSONObject(i);

                                if (JOUserData.has("uid")) {
                                    String getUserID = JOUserData
                                            .getString("uid");
                                }

                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        /*
                         * try { editor.putString("access_expires",
                         * facebook.request("me"));
                         * 
                         * try { JSONObject json =
                         * Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me", values));
                         * String userId = json.getString("id");
                         * 
                         * } catch (FacebookError e) { // TODO
                         * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
                         * catch (JSONException e) { // TODO Auto-generated
                         * catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
                         * 
                         * Log.i(TAG, facebook.request("me")); } catch
                         * (MalformedURLException e) { // TODO
                         * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
                         * catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated
                         * catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
                         */
                        editor.commit();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error

                        Log.wtf(TAG, error);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors
                        Log.wtf(TAG, fberror);
                    }

                });
    }
}
```

In my app login screen "Login with Facebook" button is there
if user click on it app shows facebook login sccreen after entering the user details , 
here how can in get the ID's .

Comment: You mean all ID's of users who are using **your application**?

Comment: who are login with facebook details in my application...

Comment: So you want to know the ID of the user _after_ he / she has logged in to your app?

Comment: yes,after user entering the details 
i would like to find the id.

Comment: Don't post images. Paste the code in text form.

Comment: I am still unable to understand your problem (not about pasting the code). The code block I gave you is supposed to be run after authenticating. Why are you trying to do that in your login method?

Comment: after using the code i am getting error

Comment: Lets continue this in chat if thats all right with you

Comment: in my profile u can find question related to error

Comment: i attached screenshots as well

Comment: You really must find a way to paste the code. I can't make heads or tails from the screenshots. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

After the user has logged in, use this code:

```
try {
    // PROFILE DETAILS AND FRIENDS COUNTER
    String queryUserInfo = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = me()";

    Bundle paramUserInfo = new Bundle();
    paramUserInfo.putString("method", "fql.query");
    paramUserInfo.putString("query", queryUserInfo);

    String responseUserInfo = Utility.mFacebook.request(paramUserInfo);

    JSONArray JAUserData = new JSONArray(responseUserInfo);

    for (int i = 0; i < JAUserData.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject JOUserData = JAUserData.getJSONObject(i);

        if (JOUserData.has("uid")) {
            String getUserID = JOUserData.getString("uid");
        }

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will give you the logged in user's ID and will be cast into the `String getUserID`. I run this piece of code in the first activity after the user has successfully logged in (regardless of having used the *Facebook Single Sign On* or the *mobile login*)

The code is still valid as long as the user is logged in, and it can be run in any activity. Also, I typically use this code block in an `Asynctask`.

Comment: Please post the code in your OP. That will make it easier to look at and understand.

Comment: sorry siddharth i dont know how to do that

Comment: @srithatsmyname: Edit your original question and then paste the code from the comments.

Comment: String responseUserInfo = Utility.mFacebook.request(paramUserInfo);
 here i am getting error

Comment: @srithatsmyname: Post the error too. the entire logcat if you would.

Comment: String responseUserInfo = Util.facebook
                                    .request(paramUserInfo);
    here i am getting above error

Comment: It should be **Utility.mFacebook** _NOT_ **Util.facebook**

Comment: And when I said paste the error code, I meant in the OP not in comments. No can keep track of all happenings via comments.